# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices

Tags: python, loops, typeerror

I'm trying to visualize a network. Info is read from a .csv file. All nodes are Objects in a list. The Objects contain a list as well. I keep running into TypeError errors: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Router

I tried casting in the 2nd for loop, all sorts of loops but whenever I try the 2nd loop it breaks

### Add edges between nodes to network

```py
for a in node_list:
    for e in node_list[a].dst:
        ams_net.add_edge(node_list[e].name, node_list[e].dst[e])
```

I need it to run through all the nodes in node_list and for each destination a node has an "edge" has to be created...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for a in node_list:
    for e in a.dst:
        ecp_net.add_edge(a.name, e)
```

since `a` and `e` are not indices, but elements of your list

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Now I run into the following problem: e is now seen as a str.
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: Could you share a little bit more of your code? I don't know what `node_list` looks like and what elements it contains.

Comment: I think i got it! used a.name and a.dst. Thanks a lot

Comment: ```python
for a in node_list:
    for e in a.dst:
        ecp_net.add_edge(a.name, e)
```

This did it and makes a lot of sense in hindsight

Comment: If I helped you, and you believe my answer contains correct solution, you could also accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sure. Maybe you could edit the post with the final solution? Could help others

Comment: Yeah, sure thing